# how to use value of a variable that was calculated inside a loop in java

Tags: java, loops

` 
    public static int Digits(int n){

```
int nbr=0,count=0;

while (nbr!=0){
nbr= nbr/10;
count++;

}
return count;}`
```

I'm sorry if this question seems silly but I've never taken any java outside university and I have an assignment. The exercise asks to state whether the number of digits of an integer is smaller, equal, or bigger than the number of digits of another integer using method. For this purpose, I used a while loop in the method which tells me the count of the number of digits of a given integer.

I know that I have to declare a variable outside the loop if I want to use it outside the loop.However, I have to initialize it outside the loop so I can use it inside the loop. But I want the value of the count after it has been calculated inside the loop and I'm not able to do this although I tried really hard and searched for answers but didn't find any.

Comment: Just initialize it to be zero outside of the loop.

Comment: Code in the post is worth a million words

Comment: Can you provide me some code? What do you already have? What did you already tried? And what is already given in the exercise?

Comment: @LyubomirPapazov I did initialize it to be zero outside the loop but then when I want to use it outside the loop its value is always zero and I don't want this

Comment: After you have declared it outside of the loop, you are setting it to 0 on every iteration.

Remove the ```count=0``` on the first line inside the loop.

Comment: @C4mps I linked a photo if you click on the blue 1 after my post you can see it

Comment: And setting it to 0 before the loop is not a problem

Comment: @LyubomirPapazov I also tried removing it and still I can't get the value that's inside the loop

Comment: One other problem is that since you have initialized ```nbr=0``` and your loop is ```while (nbr!=0)```, the loop will never start. Maybe your loop should be ```while (n!=0)```, or better: set ```nbr=n``` in the line above

Comment: And the int to check, `n`, is never used in the method. I think what you want is `int nbr = n;` before the loop

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use  the debugger to solve simple issues like this.

Comment: welcome to SO! I took the liberty to edit your question, but it still needs some editing from your part. For once, if you copy the code (as text) in your question, it is much easier to read and understand. See here how to produce a [minimal and reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your program and maybe this will help you [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you your quesiton won't be closed or downvoted. As long as you can show that you did your research and that your question is serious, people will gladly help you!

Comment: Thank you everyone I got the answer and I'll try to ask better questions next time. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to delete `count = 0` inside the loop because it will always be 0. Second thing is that your while condition (`nbr! = 0`) is never true because in declaration you set it to 0

Below function return number of digits in number passed as argument

```
public static int Digits(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        count++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hi @JanaHalawani would be nice if you update your question, changing the image for your code... Using the **code markdown** if possible. 

This approach will make your question easier to understand and to be reached by search engines. 

I know that you already have your answer, but other developers could have the same issue. So, let make this question more readable to others. 

Cheers,

Comment: @JonatasEmidio thank you for your advice. I think I did what you meant. Sorry but this is my first time on this site and I'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

There are couples of fixes/improvements needed in this code.

- Digits variable is not used.
- nbr is always 0 and not assigned the value of n.
- On each iteration, count is reset to 0.
- It doesn't consider 0, it is digit of one length.

```
      public static int countOfDigits(int n) {
            if (n == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            int count = 0;
            while (n != 0) {
                n = n / 10;
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
```